# A1 and B1 memory slots don't work, while A2 and B2 do

Tags: memory, bsod, memory-management

I recently build my own PC, with a Z790 motherboard a intel i5 13K Alder Lake and a single 32 gb DDR5 ram stick.

When trying to install windows, I had a lot of problems, most often a MEMORY_MANAGEMENT BSOD.

I tried a lot of fixes like updating the BIOS and disabling memory related settings in the BIOS.

Long story short, after a lot of troubleshooting I figured out that when I moved my ram into the 2nd or 4th slot (A1 respectively B1), memtest failed almost all the tests with more than 10K errors, while the other 2 slots worked perfectly with 0 errors.

Now, I tried reseating the ram multiple times to no avail, so I can only conclude It's either the CPU or the motherboard.

What I want to know is could reseating the CPU fix the issue?

Comment: if this is a new build, and you can. return the RAM stick and get a replacement as 2x16GB chips (in the same package preferably, and of a model on the mobo HCL). if you are getting BSODs on windows install, somthing is clearly wrong, and if you have disassembled and reassembled a couple times, and consulted the manual, then its time to consider malfunctioning or incompatible parts. while reseating the CPU due to evidence of Thermal problems with the heatsink is somthing you might want to do for an older PC, if the CPU is properly detected by UEFI, then it is likely correctly installed.

Comment: Many motherboards recommend filling the A2 and B2 slots first - check page 30 of the manual at https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MAG-Z790-TOMAHAWK-WIFI/support#manual. Ot might be simply that you get errors in the A1 B1 slots because you are getting signal reflections from unfitted slots. The reason for this is that A2 is likely the end of the channel A chain.

Comment: Did you read the manual where the memory should be installed if there is a single module?

Comment: @Mokubai I think youre right, It's noted to "Always fill the DIMM2 slots first". It's still weird it boots in a weird corrupted state, but the errors in memtest84 are wrong memory location error. So maybe the lookup offset is wrong because of the ram placing. But at the same time, my motherboard is a Gigabyte, not MSI and I can't find that reference in the Gigacute manual

Comment: @codex it's possible that the signals are *almost* okay but there will be a random factor in play as to when errors occur. The errors depend more on circuit behaviour over time due to the effects of the pcb trace than they do the actual memory or slot itself. If there were a problem with the CPU or memory itself I would expect it to not work at all, not for it to kinda work sometimes.

Comment: @Codex page 16 of https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_z790-ae-series_e_221118.pdf?v=672a72e0a0eed6a8be6ff24ef4d196fb in the "installing memory" section gives the same advice "When installing a single memory module, we recommend that you install it in the DDR5_A2/
DDR4_A2 socket" and there is a table that says to use the A2 B2 slots first.

Comment: @Mokubai Ah, I see. I didn't notice that as I skimmed the document for keywords. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may well be normal.

Many motherboards recommend filling the A2 and B2 slots first - check page 30 of the manual at http://msi.com/Motherboard/MAG-Z790-TOMAHAWK-WIFI/support#manual.

[image]

The [Gigabyte manual I found](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_z790-ae-series_e_221118.pdf) has the same advice. For dual channel operation (the table in the image) you should fit the A2 B2 sockets first, and for a single DIMM it should always go in the A2 slot as shown in the note beneath:

[image]

It might be simply that you get errors in the A1 B1 slots because you are getting signal reflections from unfitted slots. The reason for this is that A2 is likely the end of the channel A chain and therefore by fitting in slots A1 first you are ending up with a memory stick with a long length of wire after it. The result is an signal stub where [electrons are bouncing back and forth](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/637191/max-stub-length-on-digital-signals) without driving into a proper load and that sort of thing causes signal integrity problems. It might be that particular patterns cause worse issues.